# Mysql table optimization for better performance

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-5.6

```
CREATE TABLE Car (
`id` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE Checkpoints (
  `id` bigint(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `check_point_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `expected_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_car_id` (`car_id`),
  KEY `car` (`check_point_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


mysql> select * from car;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Ferrari |
+----+---------+

mysql> select * from Checkpoints;
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | car_id | check_point_name | expected_time       | actual_time         |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Point1           | 2021-02-01 15:00:00 | 2021-02-15 15:01:00 |
|  2 |      1 | Point2           | 2021-02-01 15:20:00 | 2021-02-01 15:23:19 |
|  3 |      1 | Point3           | 2021-02-01 15:30:00 | 2021-02-01 15:32:19 |
|  4 |      1 | Point4           | 2021-02-01 15:40:00 | 2021-02-01 15:40:19 |
|  5 |      1 | Point5           | 2021-02-01 15:50:00 | 2021-02-01 15:50:19 |
|  6 |      1 | Point5           | 2021-02-01 15:50:00 | 2021-02-01 15:50:00 |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Current mysql version : 5.6.44

For every car there will be multiple check points and their expected times & actual times of arrival. Problem which I am facing track_car table keeps growing into huge table in size which is resulting in slow queries and resulting in mysql performance (Above is the best example I can come up to explain the problem :)).

In order to optimize this table thinking of moving track_car data to JSON/Text single row holding JSON string with all these values.

Can anyone suggest if we any other approach to solve this growing table.

Comment: Is there any correlation between the eta of the first checkpoint and subsequent checkpoints (it seems like there is)

Comment: Yes there is, this is kind of a Plan and then tracking actual track of plan. Thanks for pointing out, have updated table name (Mybad)

Comment: So you don't need to store that information. You only need to store the checkpoint, the car, and the actual time. And one row for each entry seems like a sensible approach. If you had a thousand cars and a thousand checkpoints, this would amount to 1 million rows - a trivial number for a modern database engine.

Comment: In real world i have seen table grow to 130G. Car is just an example, in real world we data in Car like table is 7- 8Lakh/day and let's assume 6 checkpoints each for these data per day.

Comment: I think we can put that firmly in the realm of 'medium'. Still, if the times are something you want to search against, I would be wary of stuffing them in to JSON, etc.

Comment: Do you really need all the track data all the time? For me it seems, that you could optimize in moving less used data (perhaps very old data) to an other table and so split the track table into something like years

Comment: We have seen during querying & insertion on this table resulting in slow queries during peak load, that was kinda concern for me. Hence thought of getting this optimized, and query will alway be on car_id.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff We don't need this all time you're right, and we do keep clearing this data time to time, with an archival policy. However problem we are facing is during peak days when we have high scale

Comment: Storing this data in json would actually increase the table size, since even the numbers and dates will be stored as text. There is not much you can improve on the table structure here (indexes on the dates if you want to perform searches on dates). If you indeed have a database growing by 7-800k/day, then you probably have to tweak your configuration, upgrade to a newer mysql version, or just invest into a better hardware / cloud service.

Comment: Can you please show example queries that run too slow?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner # Time: 190916 21:15:27
# Query_time: 1.262249  Lock_time: 0.000049  Rows_sent: 7  Rows_examined: 7  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 1817
SET timestamp=1568648727;
SELECT `Checkpoints`.* FROM `Checkpoints`  WHERE `Checkpoints`.`car_id` = 1134110281;

Comment: @ThorstenKettner # Query_time: 1.011947 Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0 Rows_affected: 1 # Bytes_sent: 19 SET timestamp=1568129618; INSERT INTO Checkpoints (actual_time, expected_time, car_id, check_point_name) VALUES ('2019-09-10 21:08:26', '2019-09-10 21:03:37', 11281530, 'Point4');

Comment: What query is getting slower as you increase the size of the table??

Comment: @RickJames both queries are slow, if we see query output which i have shared have taken time more than a sec.

Comment: @user1719039 - Neither of those queries should take that long; sounds like something else was bogging down the whole system.